# IOP double column manuscript unable to print figures in pdf

Tags: floats

I am trying to write for IOP, when i use multicol package latex cannot print figure , for single column article no problem occur at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you have `\begin{figure}....\end{figure}` within `multicols` environment --> no figure will be printed, since `multicols` deactivates `figure`

Comment: The IOP template does not support multicol on the class level. The journal staff will create the double-column format, when a paper is accepted. I know that you could circumvent this by introducing multicol environments, but what's the benefit?